# Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::createfromformat()

Tags: php, mysql

How do you solve the error of:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::createfromformat()
```

The error is happening at line 35. This is what my code reads from line 31 to 45

```
// check database for necessary updates

$update = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rent WHERE colour='#3C0'");
while($row_update = mysql_fetch_array( $update )) {
    $datetime_lower   = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $min);
    $datetime_upper   = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $max);
    $datetime_compare = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y g:i a', $row_update['pDate']);
    if ($datetime_lower < $datetime_compare && $datetime_upper > $datetime_compare) {
        // date is between do nothing
    } else {
        // date is not between so update
        $update_result = mysql_query("UPDATE rent SET colour='#F0F0F0' WHERE id=" . $row_update['id'] . " && colour='#3C0'");
        mysql_close($update_result);
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: By removing that line. The error will go away then. Generally it's a good idea to not call undefined functions because otherwise it will always result in a fatal error. Probably you can link the function from the PHP manual you wanted to call so it's clear what you try to do?

Comment: Either you made a mistake when copying the errormessage, or its not the file to it: `createfromformat != createFromFormat`

Comment: The code seems to work fine on my local server though

Comment: What PHP version are you using? `DateTime` is available in 5.3 and later.

Comment: Guys, there is typo... cooldown...)

Comment: @Michael my uk2.net server is running on PHP 5.2.9 - not sure how to upgrade it

Comment: @devdRew: Also method and class names are case-insensitive anyway.

Comment: That's a great news... (went to byte myself)...

Comment: @methuselah You cannot use `DateTime` then. You'll need to use the old date functions instead.

Comment: @Michael Can you recommend any to fit the context of my code?

Comment: Found this: date("j M Y", strtotime($myDate)) solved the issue for me on an older server where i couldn't upgrade my version manually and couldn't wait for the guys to do so.

Answer (score 21):

[DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) was introduced in php 5.3. And most likely you have older one. So - install php >= 5.3 and you'll get it worked.

Comment: PHP version 5.2.9 - I am running it on a uk2.net server

Comment: Is there an equivalent approach for servers running earlier versions of PHP (PHP < 5.3)?

Comment: @Sam: `strtotime`, not equivalent, but could help

Answer (score 5):

Which version of PHP are you running? According to [PHP](http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), `createDateFormat` is available in versions >= 5.3.0.

-- Edit

Looks like your code was using DateTime incorrectly, in that createFromFormat returns an object, not a string, but you should be able to transpose the DateTime::createFromFormat() calls with [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)() calls.

```
// PHP >= 5.3.0
$datetime_lower   = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $min);
$datetime_upper   = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $max);
$datetime_compare = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y g:i a', $row_update['pDate']);

// PHP < 5.3.0
$datetime_lower   = date('d/m/Y', $min);
$datetime_upper   = date('d/m/Y', $max);
$datetime_compare = date('d/m/Y g:i a', $row_update['pDate']);
```

It seems to me though, that if you are dealing with timestamps, you can do the comparison ops without having to convert to a specific format. If one of the dates you are dealing with isn't in a timestamp format you can do the following:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($yourFormattedDateTime);

// Now with everything in ints, you can do your conditional evals
```

Comment: PHP version 5.2.9 - I am running it on a uk2.net server

Comment: Not sure why they running such an old version, you will have to contact them to get them to upgrade, use an supported function call for date/time manipulation for 5.2.9, or find a new host who is more up to date with their software.

Comment: Can you recommend any supported function calls?

Comment: @methuselah: Were you able to figure it out?